# Mysql slow query on large table

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.6

With Mysql 5.6.10, I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `es_user_action` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `company_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `work_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `action` tinyint(2) NOT NULL COMMENT '10, 20, 30, 40',
  `action_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `apply_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `apply_display_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `action_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `scout_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `register_datetime_sorting` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_pending` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `apply_status` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '2' COMMENT '1: paid, 2: free',
  `has_response` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `response_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_shown` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '1',
  `source` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_company_work` (`user_id`,`work_id`,`company_id`,`apply_id`,`source`),
  KEY `IDX_2` (`company_id`,`is_shown`,`apply_status`,`apply_id`,`work_id`,`action_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=436896779 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The full query I want to perform on the table would be the following:

```
SELECT
    `id` AS `seqNo`,
    `company_id` AS `companyId`,
    `work_id` AS `workId`,
    `action` AS `userActionType`,
    `action_time` AS `userActionDatetime`,
    `is_pending`,
    `apply_status`,
    `action_id`,
    `source`,
    `user_id` AS `userId`,
    `apply_display_id`  
FROM
    `es_user_action`
WHERE
    `company_id` = 449664
    AND `is_shown` = 1 
    AND `apply_status` = 1
    AND `apply_id` = 0
    AND `action_time` >= '2021-01-05 15:56:14'
-- AND `work_id` IN ( 1250160 )     
ORDER BY
    is_pending ASC,
    action ASC,
    score DESC,
CASE
        source 
        WHEN "entenshoku" THEN
        action_time 
    END DESC,
CASE
        
        WHEN source <> "entenshoku" THEN
        action_time 
END ASC
    LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

The table has around 15 million rows and the following query takes around 15 seconds. Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED:**

This is the explain query result:
[image: explain query]

**UPDATED 4/2/2021:**

Handler counts result:

[image: handler counts]

Comment: Please use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and provide the result so you and others can see and discuss the query plan.

Comment: @geertjanvdk I have updated

Comment: Focus on the the 'filesort', so the sort buffer might be too small. But, yeah, your query might need some tweaking indeed. (just want to make sure the query plan is added).

Comment: @geertjanvdk could you explain for me?

Comment: Have you considered, 
WHERE
    `company_id` = 449664
    AND `action_time` >= '2021-01-05 15:56:14' 
    AND `is_shown` = 1 
    AND `apply_status` = 1
    AND `apply_id` = 0
with index sequence the same as this list?

Answer (score 1):

IDX_2 is the best index for that query *when the test for `work_id` is included*.  The `ORDER BY` is too complex for any index to help.

If you need to exclude `work_id`, then make an index without it.

The table is probably under 2GB; how big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Most of the `BIGINTs` are likely to be overkill.  Shrinking them from that 8-byte size would shrink the table.  But that probably would not help the 15 seconds much.

Comment: ```innodb_buffer_pool_size is``` 20915945472. I can't find any ways to optimize

Comment: @ThaiNguyenHung - Let's get a little more insight into what is going on.  Use this to get the Handler counts:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Comment: I have updated it. Please help me

Comment: @ThaiNguyenHung - Ah; I did not notice that the test on `work_id` was commented out.  I made changes to my Answer.  (The EXPLAIN showed 4 "const", I was expecting 5.)

Comment: work_id is optional so only has 4 consts

Comment: @ThaiNguyenHung - Then add this index:  INDEX(`company_id`, `is_shown`, `apply_status`, `apply_id`, `action_time`)

Comment: a little faster

Comment: but when query with work_id, it will be slow

Comment: @ThaiNguyenHung - Hence the need for _both_ indexes.  The Optimizer will pick the appropriate one depending on the presence of `work_id`.

Comment: thank u so much. do you have any idea for the order by query?

Comment: @ThaiNguyenHung - The current `ORDER BY` unsolvable problems:  (1) Mixing ASC and DESC; (2) expressions.  (1) is solved in MySQL 8.0, but there is no way to optimize expressions -- other than by getting rid of them.  That means changing the business logic or the user expectations.

Comment: I understand. thank u so much